# Many to Many JPA join query

Tags: java, spring, jpa, many-to-many

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer", schema = "customer")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(columnDefinition = "uuid", updatable = false, name = "customer_id")
    private UUID customerId;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "bookMembers")
    Set<Reservation> reservations
  

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "reservation", schema = "reservation")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Reservation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(columnDefinition = "uuid", updatable = false, name = "reservation_id")
    private UUID reservationId;

    @JoinColumn(name = "reservation_id")
    @Column(name = "reserved_by_customer_id")
    private UUID reservedByCustomerId;

    @JoinColumn(name = "menu_id")
    private UUID menuId;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "reservation_customer",
            schema = "customer",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "reservation_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")}
    )
    private Set<Customer> reservationMembers = new HashSet<>();

}

Dao Entity

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MenuCount {

    private UUID menuId;
    private Long count;
}

Repository

public interface ReservationRepository extends JpaRepository<Reservation, UUID> {
@Query("select new com.de.dao.MenuCount(r.menuId, count(c.customerId)) from customer c join c.reservations r  group by r.menuId")
    List<MenuCount> getCustomerCountGroupByMenuId();
}
```

I am trying to get the total number of customers for each menu Id. But when running the code getting the below error

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'Repository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.de.repository.Repository.getCustomerCountGroupByMenuId()!

Native -

select r.menuId, count(c.customerId) from Customer c join reservation_customer cr on c.customerId = cr.customerId join Reservation r on r.reservationId = cr.reservationId groupBy r.menuId;

Can I acheive the native query functionality using @Query() in JPA without creating an additional entity module

Comment: The answer is probably in the manual.

Comment: __List<TrailCount>__ versus __new com.de.dao.MenuCount__

Comment: @DirkDeyne sorry it was a typing mistake. I updated my question

Comment: Is there more to the exception that shows Springs objection to the query? JPA queries (non-native) use the entity and property names: entity name for Customer is "Customer" - you've got it lower case in the query.

Comment: @Chris query is not shown even though show sql is enabled in the property file. Also I updated the proper entity names and still showing the same error

Comment: Show SQL options only come into play when there is SQL to execute - validation is occurring well before that. The error itself should give a reason for the validation failure. If entity names are now correct (Update your question to show what you now have, as what was there was/is wrong), show the full error stack as well - and check the log for the statements before the validation as well. The issue might not just be with your query, but your model itself is wrong. What are you trying to get with JoinColumn annotations on UUID columns? They are for reference mappings to define FKs, not basics